# Use of a Polygon for VoronoiDiagramBuilder.setClipEnvelope instead of rectangle

Tags: java, gis, geospatial, jts

I am generating voronoi polygons from large number of points(coordinates) using the JTS topology suite.

```
VoronoiDiagramBuilder voronoi=new VoronoiDiagramBuilder();
voronoi.setTolerance(0.001);
voronoi.setSites(coordinates);
voronoi.setClipEnvelope(...);
Geometry geo =voronoi.getDiagram(new GeometryFactory());
```

the method  voronoi.setClipEnvelope only accepts rectangle(boundingbox), however I want a custom polygon instead of a bounding box so no voronoi diagrams are generated that are larger than the custom polygon.

is this possible? using this API, or perhaps another component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best (only?) way to do this is to compute the voronoi diagram for the envelope and then clip it to your polygon using something like:

```
Geometry out = geo.intersection(polygon);
```

Comment: the "polygon" in your answer...is my 'custom' polygon?